# Problem with editing a container with theme.res

Tags: codenameone

I have a problem to edit the background color of my container. Its UIID is equal to null when i check the component inspector. But in my code, i've indeed set the UIID for this component to modify it:

```
    Container container = new Container(new BorderLayout());
    container.setName("CardReaderButton");
    container.setUIID("componentLeader");
```

[image]

[image]

Test2, Test1 and Test are just 3 buttons in the container.

[image]

Comment: UIID's should never be null so this is odd. Even if your set UIID failed it should have been "Container" not null. So something else isn't working here which I can't see. Is there anything else going on within the application?

Comment: I'm Sorry Shai, I've found the problem, it was really ridiculous ... I haven't given the right UIID value to my components ...